# How can i create boolean filter component in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

It's quite sad that ag-grid doesn't provide a simple boolean filter component. They have number filter, text filter, date filter component, just not boolean filter :( We are using viewport row-model and have a column which shows boolean values, true/false and we want to have a simple filter which shows true/false which we can select and then filter. I know set-filter is the closest to this and I tried that, it works to an extent after making some assumptions on server, but it doesn't seem clean enough for this simple use-case. Also, there are few issues with set-filter customization:

1. Even if I provide "values" in the set-filter as [true, false], ag-grid considers them as strings ['true', 'false'] which is a bit cumbersome.
2. Set-filter provides multi-select checkboxes in the filter, which is not at all ideal for selecting boolean values, like it doesn't make sense to select both true/false and then filter. It should be single select radio button or something similar.
3. We can't set filterType or anything as part of filterParams like how it happens for existing number/text filter. This is important from server implementation point of view because then I could have set `filterType=boolean` in ag-grid and then server would have handled cleanly.

Hence, we set out to ask that has anyone implemented this sort of simple boolean filter component? Please feel free to direct to any helpful docs or if anything I really overlooked/missed.

Comment: I need the same thing - odd it doesn't have it

Answer (score 3):

I am total newbie and my solution is still not finished but perhaps it might help someone to go forward.
We also needed a boolean filter and my colleague suggested to make a custom filter with just two options: "approved" and "not approved" (in our case). Remember to convert boolean to numbers since ag-grid allows to filter only on text, numbers and dates. I did that with + operator next to the cell value.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjUrU.jpg)

What you will need:
https://ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/filter-provided-simple/#custom-filter-options

My filter ended being something like this:

```
    const booleanFilter: INumberFilterParams = {
    filterOptions: [
        {
            displayKey: 'true',
            displayName: 'True',
            predicate: (_, cellValue) => +cellValue === 1,
            numberOfInputs: 0,
        },
        {
            displayKey: 'false',
            displayName: 'False',
            predicate: (_, cellValue) => +cellValue === 0,
            numberOfInputs: 0,
        }
    ] as IFilterOptionDef[],
    suppressAndOrCondition: true,
};
```

add this filter to your column in ag-grid

```
                {
                field: 'fieldName',
                filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
                filterParams: booleanFilter
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It is a no brainer to have a boolean filter, however ag grid lacks real boolean filter. I ended up adding "empty" as first value in the array, this way you get "Choose one" option if nothing is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use AdapTable with AG Grid?
We do and they provide a boolean filter automatically for any boolean column.
They also provide a way to make the whole column show checkbox values as well (https://docs.adaptabletools.com/guide/handbook-column-formatting#checkbox-column-style) but that might be overkill for your requirements.

Comment: Note that AdapTable is not free for use for commercial or enterprise software

Answer (score 0):

create an external button and add this on click event

```
const handleFilter = useCallback(() => {
  gridRef.current!.api.setFilterModel({
    disabled: { type: 'true' },
  });
}, []);
```